# Properly Structuring a Tkinter Application

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, model-view-controller, tkinter

I'm fairly new to object oriented programming and while I understand the basic concepts, I'm still having some trouble organizing my applications. I'm building a small Tkinter application and trying to make sure I follow correct object oriented principles. I have a couple specific questions regarding what I've done so far (I appreciate any and all suggestions however!).

- Is it correct to use static methods often? I wanted to separate the logic from the rest of the application and I realized I'd be writing quite a few static methods from the way I structured my app
- Would it be better to create a class for every widget separately? I created my Frame classes (see code below) and packed them with the widgets that goes into that specific frame. This causes the Frame classes to be quite large
- I quite like the MVC architecture overall. Is it generally a good architecture to follow when designing GUI application?

I included the left frame only with no widgets just to illustrate my code structure. I was planning to structure the top and right frames in the same manner.

**CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

# I kept the database in the global scope
con = sqlite3.connect('../database/a_db.db')
cur = con.cursor()

# Controls all of the logic
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_tasks():
        query = ''' SELECT * FROM tasks '''
        tasks = cur.execute(query).fetchall()
        return tasks

    @staticmethod
    def get_task_details(selected_task_id):
        query = '''SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_id=? '''
        db_task = cur.execute(query, (selected_task_id,))
        db_task_details = db_task.fetchall()[0][2]
        return db_task_details

    @staticmethod
    def get_task_status(selected_task_id):
        query = ''' SELECT assigned.emp_id FROM assigned
                    INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.task_id = assigned.task_id
                    WHERE assigned.task_id=? '''

        db_active_task = cur.execute(query, (selected_task_id,)).fetchall()
        if len(db_active_task) > 0:
            return 'Assigned'
        else:
            return 'Not Assigned'

# Controls what the user of the app sees
class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("My App")
        self.middle_of_screen()
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap(r'../images/a_logo.ico')

        # These three frames fill up the entire space
        self.top_panel = TopFrame() # Another frame with widgets
        self.left_panel = LeftFrame() 
        self.right_panel = RightFrame() # Another frame with widgets

    def display_task_details(self, status, task_details):
        if self.left_panel.list_details.get(0):
            self.left_panel.list_details.delete(0, 'end')

        self.left_panel.list_details.insert(0, "Status: {}".format(status))
        if self.left_panel.list_details:
            self.left_panel.list_details.insert(1, "Task Description: {}".format(task_details))
        else:
            self.left_panel.list_details.insert(1, "Task Description: None")

    def display_tasks(self, tasks):
        # self.left_panel.list_tasks.delete(0, 'end')
        for count, task in enumerate(tasks):
            self.left_panel.list_tasks.insert(count, '{}. {}'.format(task[0], task[1]))

    def middle_of_screen(self):
        window_width = 1350
        window_height = 750
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
        y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)

        self.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}')

    def start(self):
        self.mainloop()


class LeftFrame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(width=900, height=700, relief='sunken', bg='#e0f0f0',
                                   borderwidth=2)
        self.left_frame.pack(side='left')

        # Widgets that would fill the frame would go here

# Code runs through here only and keeps the Model and View seperated
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View()
        self.show_tasks()
        self.view.left_panel.list_tasks.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.show_task_details)

        self.view.start()

    def show_task_details(self, event):
        if self.view.left_panel.list_tasks.curselection():
            selected_task = self.view.left_panel.list_tasks.get(self.view.left_panel.list_tasks.curselection())
            selected_task_id = selected_task.split('.')[0]

            db_task_details = self.model.get_task_details(selected_task_id)
            status = self.model.get_task_status(selected_task_id)

            self.view.display_task_details(status, db_task_details)

    def show_tasks(self):
        tasks = self.model.get_tasks()
        self.view.display_tasks(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.view.start()
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd certainly recommend that you put your `sqlite.connect` inside the init of the Model class and not use static methods in this class.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll put my question there. Sorry, I wasn't sure since I did have some specific questions as well